# AppleScript - filtering selection (Yojimbo)

Tags: applescript

I'm currently trying to filter a selection with Applescript.

This works:

```
tell application "Yojimbo" to set theYojimboSelection to selection
```

but this does not:

```
tell application "Yojimbo" to set theYojimboSelection to selection where length of (name of selection) > 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need first to select all the selection and then loop through each selected item with the length criteria?

Can it be done all in one step?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use *Yojimbo*.  However, AppleScript `whose` filters need to be applied to a **plural** object.  While `selection` *is* itself a list of objects, the `selection-object` is a single entity, so cannot be enacted upon by `whose`.  `items of selection` would, in theory, be a more appropriate collection to filter, but `items` will simply generate a dereferenced `list` that, in fact, cannot be filtered either.

In other apps that use `selection-objects`, the `selection` property is annoyingly partially dereferenced and therefore not filter-able with `whose`.

If it were possible, `length of its name` (which is the syntax that would be used in such a filter) is not a valid property to filter against.

Unfortunately, based on how other apps with a similar `selection` object operate, you'll need to iterate through the list manually.

However, if efficiency is a concern, then here's a fairly efficient means of doing it, as illustrated using the `selection` object in *Finder*, which is a list of files and folders:

```
property Finder : application "Finder"


to filterItems from (L as list) thru filter as handler into |L＊| as list : null
    local L, |L＊|, filter

    if |L＊| = null then set |L＊| to {}

    script filteredItems
        property array : L
        property fn : filter
        property list : |L＊|
    end script

    tell the filteredItems to repeat with x in its array
        if fn(x) = true ¬
            then set ¬
            end of its list ¬
            to x's contents
    end repeat

    return the list of filteredItems
end filterItems


on characterCount(x)
    set |name| to the name of x
    |name|'s length > 12
end characterCount


filterItems from (Finder's selection) thru characterCount
```